# How to test Wep API client without running application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, testing, nunit, swagger-codegen

I have some api controllers and [generated](https://editor.swagger.io/) a swagger client with tests for them and filled it out. Here an example of filled test class:

```cs
[TestFixture]
public class CategoriesApiTests
{
    private CategoriesApi _instance;

    [SetUp]
    public void Init()
    {
        _instance = new CategoriesApi("http://localhost:5000/");
    }

    [Test]
    public void InstanceTest()
    {
        Assert.IsInstanceOf<CategoriesApi>(_instance, "instance is a CategoriesApi");
    }
}
```

But my tests only pass if I run my application.
How can I emulate running an application for testing?

Comment: You can publish your on IIS or somthing else. If you don't want to run app in visual studio. Or do you have other reasons?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: We use WebApplicationFactory to run our APIs inside unit tests for internal end-to-end tests.  Is that what you're looking for?  [WebApplicationFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.testing.webapplicationfactory-1?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Answer (score 0):

What you may want to do is to separate all business logic into a separate DLL and then use unit testing.

Comment: Most likely, I would like to conduct integration testing. But how can I run the application as a dummy?

Comment: How-to do unit testing for external API (like Fake API ) api.chucknorris.io ? **[simple-example-of-calling-rest-api-with-httpclient-in-net5.0](https://adamstorr.azurewebsites.net/blog/simple-example-of-calling-rest-api-with-httpclient-in-net5.0)**